# Bizzare error from Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Having this code executed in Qt editor:

```
 QPushButton button("Animated Button");
 button.show();

 QPropertyAnimation animation(&button, "geometry");
 animation.setDuration(3000);
 animation.setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, 100, 30));
 animation.setEndValue(QRect(250, 250, 100, 30));

 animation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutBounce);

 animation.start();
```

I'm getting an pop up with error msg:

[image]

Comment: Hook it with the visual studio debugger?

Answer (score 1):

You should always create your QWidgets on the heap, otherwise you'll indeed get all sorts of errors:

```
QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("Animated Button");
```

Comment: I didn't even notice that was part of the code since he formatted it incorrectly. Good catch

Comment: @Laurent thanks for your help, this bloody code is taken from http://doc.qt.nokia.com/solutions/4/qtanimationframework/animation.html so I didn't think they would screw up something as simple as this.

Comment: Indeed, this is not a good tutorial. Most likely, what's happening is that the button gets deleted when it gets out of scope, however the animation might still be referring it, and you end up with a runtime error.

Comment: That's strange, because objects go out of scope in reverse order of declaration, and therefore the animation will go out of scope _before_ the button. So there's no way it might still be referring to it.

Comment: You can create widgets on the stack. It's best not to, but I've never experienced "all sorts of errors" when doing so.

Comment: Sure he can create them on the stack, but that's just looking for troubles in my opinion. Qt is designed to manage the deletion of QWidgets by itself so it's better to let it do it.